# restore windows 7 yesterday's state

Tags: windows-7, automation

I have four computers that I lend to my grade eight students. The students use these computers in order to create various documents throughout the day. Since the computers are shared among a number of students, what I would like to accomplish is have some routine that automatically runs at the end of the day and delete all documents that were left behind by the students. Some of these documents might be found on the Desktop others in My Documents. I have no idea where to begin and would greatly appreciate any help you might give me in order to automate the process so that I may dedicate my time in a more profitable way.

Comment: Do the students all use the same account to login? Would a temporary profile be a viable solution? That is, every time someone logoff all the changes made to the profile (e.g. new files created) would be lost.

Answer (score 2):

Reboot to restore is a commonly used term in IT that refers to a technique in which the disk of a computer is automatically wiped and restored to a "clean slate", or master image every time the computer or device is restarted, rebooted or turned on.

http://www.rebootrestore.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [SteadierState](https://web.archive.org/web/20200223173933/http://steadierstate.com:80/), though the site seem to be offline at the moment.
The idea behind it is quite simple and you can do manually.

1. [Install](https://web.archive.org/web/20160219230727/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/knom/archive/2009/04/07/windows-7-vhd-boot-setup-guideline.aspx) and config windows (or coping an existing installation) on a VHD file (which we call Base).
2. Create a differencing VHD with the Base VHD as parent.
3. Create two more differencing VHDs with the last differencing VHD as parent (as shown in the picture below).
4. Config your BCD to boot from either one of them.

Now, every time you want to do a roll-back, just switch the boot config in the BCD to the other VHD, delete the old one, and create him again.

[image: VHDs tree configuration]

Here's some old script I wrote a few years back that does just that (after the initial configuration), but it might need some tweaking:

```
@Echo Off
SetLocal
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

D:
CD\VHD

Set Current=""
For /F %%F in ('dir /b /o:-s Diff-0*.vhd') do (
    Set Current=%%F
)
@Echo Current=%Current%
If Exist %Current% Del %Current%
Echo Create VDisk File=D:\VHD\%Current% Parent=D:\VHD\Diff-Base.vhd > CreateTemp.bat
DiskPart /s CreateTemp.bat
Del CreateTemp.bat
bcdedit /set {Default} Device VHD=[%~d0]\VHD\%Current%
bcdedit /set {Default} OSDevice VHD=[%~d0]\VHD\%Current%
EndLocal
```

Answer (score -1):

What about using virtual machines. You can use the VM ware of your choice. My choice would be to Start at this web site. **vmware.com** To get this started will take some time with the research time and trial and error. But I think it would be well worth the time invested.  How Vm works is it tricks the PC in to thinking that a vm file is a hard drive.  the web site above with give you more insight as to how Vm ware works and all the bells and whistles that you can add. 
You may install what ever OS your students need or you want them to use. Then you could just click revert and you are back to a fresh start install of the OS.  If you ask a member of your schools IT dept. I am sure they can give you better insight. Sorry if I have wasted your time reading this post it is Just my opinion take or leave it.

Hope I have gave you food for thought!!